# volatile variable instead of mutex protected variable to check for changed data

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a thread which basically does:

```
int changed; //global variable
..

for (;;) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
   if (changed) {
       do_changes();
       changed = 0;
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

   do_stuff();

}
```

The loop is run a few hundred thousand times a second, while the global `changed` variable will be set rarely (a few times a day) by another thread.

With a change to

```
volatile int changed; //global variable
..

for (;;) {

   if (changed) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
       do_changes();
       changed = 0;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
   }
   do_stuff();
}
```

I can measure 3-4% performance increase of the loop with this approach, which is worth while pursuing.

However volatile variables seems to be heavily discouraged. 
Are there any drawbacks with the approach here ? Any corner cases that might cause the 2. version to not work as intended ?

Comment: Are you sure the performance increase is *because* of using `volatile` and not because do_stuff() (or other part of code) is doing different things across different runs?

Comment: If the loop is run by only one thread than it is good, if not, re-check the value after the lock. Consider using std::atomic_flag instead.

Comment: @KingsIndian Yes I am sure of that.

Comment: Do you need to call `do_changes` while keeping the mutex locked?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Yes.

Comment: You may get better answers if you elaborate your problem a bit more on a higher level. How many producers and how many consumers are there?

Comment: The performance increase you see is you not locking the mutex in your second example (in an un-safe manner).

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` does not make your variable thread safe or atomic. You may like to use [C11 atomics](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly/1832575) for that.

You basically have two threads changing `changed` variable thus overwriting previous values causing data race.

I cannot recommend enough watching [atomic Weapons: The C++ Memory Model and Modern Hardware](http://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/). (It applies to C as well).

Comment: There is noone changing the `changed` variable without a lock. Notice the changed variable is only read without a lock, not written to. It will only have 2 significant values. 0 or 1. i.e. it's only used as an indication that something has changed. It is of no concern whether the check discovers the change the same iteration as some other thread changed it, or the next iteration.

Comment: There is actually no need for the volatile, it is useless for two reasons: 1. pthread_mutex enforces memory fence, 2. we are not in a loop (to check the cached value). The question is how do we use the variable? If it is checked by only one thread and the time of update is not critical (just needs to be done in some point of time), then it is all good (writing to it from multiple threads is not a problem - done under lock with memory fences - the read is the possible problem - may not see the change immediatelly)

Comment: I have to correct myself: the `volatile` is needed if do_stuff() is trivial (inlined). Then we are in a loop and never calling pthread_mutex_lock (to enforce `mfence` or the like).

Answer (score 1):

**Author: *However volatile variables seems to be heavily discouraged. Are there any drawbacks with the approach here ? Any corner cases that might cause the 2. version to not work as intended ?***

First of all: **Whenever you are tempted to use `volatile` think again if you don't need [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).** Now see what may happen:

1) It is not safe if you have the loop in multiple threads. You *can think* about duplicating the check:

```
if (changed) { // quick check
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
   if (changed) { // another thread could do the work
       ...
```

2) If your code is critical to see it was changed, you need to use atomics, because that `if(changed)` before `pthread_mutex_lock` may not see it because of cache.

3) It may work on x86(_64) with ***strong memory ordering and atomic int accesses***, but fail on other architecture. That is the reason why `volatile` is discouraged, use atomics (and make a habbit of it). **`volatile` does not force atomic usage or any other synchronization**. Atomics do (read-modify-write instructions).

```
std::atomic_flag validated;
std::mutex mx; struct MyData { ... } data;
void change() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
    data.something();
    validated.clear();
}
void validate() {
    if(!validated.test_and_set()) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
        data.update();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You will never know for sure if data is valid or not unless you hold the lock and use another variable for it.

4) Just try your original code with pthread_spinlock_t

5) Little advice: don't play God with synchronization unless you really know, what you are doing. You can switch from mutex to spinlock (written by somebody else) and do some benchmarking.

**About edits and comments:** The original answer just started with 1) nothing before. As it turned out, some people neither read the full question nor the full answer. Pitty those quick downvoters. This site is not facebook and those votes should be eihter **is helpful** or **is not helpful**, these up/downvotes are no likes and dislikes like on facebook! I may disagree with some parts of the other answers, but still think they ***are*** helpful, although incomplete (not aswering the full question, but only a part of it) or partially incorrent (there is nothing bad in writing same value to variable from many threads if we know that we can do that without problems).

Comment: As written this answer appears to give _solutions_ not to "show problems", because it isn't written in the form "You might consider doing this ... but that doesn't work because ...". Also, (1) is broken for more reasons than just cache effects, see the discussion in http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf pointing out that `volatile` might have no effect on inter-thread optimisations

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The author's question ends with *Are there any drawbacks with the approach here ? Any corner cases that might cause the 2. version to not work as intended ?* So is my answer, one possible problem by one. We don't know how it is used, it can actually work as intended, but need other conditions to be satisfied (single thread doing update and no need to have it updated immediatelly, just some time).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a C11 environment that support them you can use [atomic variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). If your system supports it, they use special instructions to achieve atomicity, instead of locks. If your system don't support that, they use locks (the flag type is always lockless).

If you don't have C11, but you have a GCC-compatible compiler see the [sync](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) family of functions. It's similar (but older) to the C11 atomic variables but if your system don't support them they generate a function call.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good idea to make it volatile to ensure that the compiler is not doing unwanted optimizations, but it doesn't make it atomic.

If there are more threads reading "changed" it could happen that one thread updates "changed" to 0 when there's another thread waiting to execute do_changes(), which will happen once the mutex is released because the condition was already evaluated.

If you want to avoid this then move the if statement inside the mutex protected space.

Hope this helps.

Carles.

Comment: It is really a bad idea to use `volatile` for multi-threading, do not do that.

Comment: Despite the downvotes it is safe to us the `volatile` *if you know the architecture* and you wrote "*but it doesn't make it atomic*" yourself, so, those downvoters are probably unable to read properly. +1 as counterbalance.

Comment: @firda `volatile` is neither safe nor sufficient for multi-threading and it requires a guru-level engineer to _know the architecture_ and use it correctly. Even then, using `volatile` prevents the compiler from doing optimizations which are otherwise done when using atomics. You may like to watch that "atomic Weapons" video, it is an eye-opener really.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I know the drawbacks of volatile (treated like being atomic for the reason it worked on old PCs). I agree that it is better to not play God and use atomics where they belong. But I do not agree with the downvotes, that's all - read the full sentence before beeing too quick on downvoting ;)

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin It would be great if you could talk about specifics related to the code in question instead of generally. Note the variable in question is not written to without a lock, there is no dependency on the variable being atomically read or written - the only real concern that someone have brought up seems to be if the variable is checked in several threads (which is not the case).

Comment: @user1255770, why do you think there is no dependency on it being accessed atomically? Nothing prevents one thread reading the variable while the other is writing it. Even if the write is atomic that's still a data race (i.e. undefined behaviour). So talking about the specifics of the code in question: it's not safe, and statements like _"Note the variable in question is not written to without a lock, there is no dependency on the variable being atomically read or written"_ imply you should not be trying to make code like this work, it's not safe.

Comment: Or in other words: It doesn't matter that it's only written to while the lock is held, **you still shouldn't read it without a lock**.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm downvoted here, probably I didn't express correctly what most of you are also stating...

Comment: @Carles, I voted down for the statement _"It is a good idea to make it volatile"_. It's not a good idea, `volatile` should not be used for this purpose.

Comment: @Carles: quick downvoters are unable to read properly, I got downvoted too despite the fact we both pointed out to use atomics. I have even described all the drawbacks one by one, still -1.

Comment: @firda, I can read fine,  your (1) with double-checked locking is broken.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No you cannot, my 2) explains why it is broken.

Comment: @firda learn to write. Don't give broken solutions then say "do something else if you need X". Just don't give the broken solution, period. Bad advice is still bad advice even if you later give better advice and so will get downvoted. Don't give bad advice.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: He wanted explanation, he got explanation. Just another blind man... good bye

Comment: What I was trying to say is that In a low level multi-process architecture it is good to use volatile variables to avoid unwanted compiler optimizations BUT in the case of the example it doesn't help at all, and I tried to explain it using an example later... I'm sorry I didn't explain it well. Anyway, at least it served to create some debate here...

Comment: @Carles: This community is like facebook - +1 are likes, picture with prettry cat will get thousands of likes, but postes where you need to think... you know ;)

Comment: @firda if you edit your answer to remove the bad advice at the start it would be a good answer ... but as it stands it isn't a good answer compared to the other ones that don't start with broken code. If you don't like the downvotes write a better answer, simple. THat's what the edit feature is for.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I hope you like it now. BTW: Those other answers do not describe what is wrong, authoritative and without explanation. I don't like such answers.